# Issue with different scopes when using this.trySend()

Tags: kotlin, firebase-storage

I am trying to upload an image into Firebase Storage, returning an Flow containing the download url.
The problem is, that apparently the this in the onCompleteListener is different from the one of the callbackflow.
It's hard to describe, but I think the code will make the issue clear.

```
fun uploadImage(eventId: String, imageUri: String) : Flow<String> = callbackFlow {
        val uri = imageUri.toUri()
        val storageRef = storage.reference
        val imageRef = storageRef.child(eventId).child("large.jpg")
        val uploadTask = imageRef.putFile(uri)

        val returnFlow = this

        uploadTask.continueWithTask {task ->
            if (!task.isSuccessful) {
                task.exception?.let {
                    throw it
                }
            }
            imageRef.downloadUrl
        }.addOnCompleteListener { task ->
            if (task.isSuccessful) {
                // this.trySend here doesn't go outside and the collect never triggers
                // storing the outer this in a variable like in returnFlow doesn't work either
                task.let { returnFlow.trySend(task.result.toString()).isSuccess }
            } else {
                // Handle failures
                // ...
            }
        }
        // this.trySend here works
        this.trySend("")

        awaitClose()
    }
```

The function is called here:

```
class AddEvent(private val repository: Repository) {
    suspend operator fun invoke(
        imageUri : String
    ) {
        val uuid = UUID.randomUUID().toString()
        repository.uploadImage(uuid, imageUri).collect{
            // Do something with the image url

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Are you just trying to get the `this` from the callback flow? Then use `this@callbackFlow.trySend`. Your IDE should automatically do that if you inline the `returnFlow` variable. Edit: I just noticed you said that "doesn't work either". What doesn't work about it?

Comment: @Jorn yes thats what I was trying, but even after doing that the functions collect() doesnt trigger

Answer (score 0):

I was literally going through the same issue.

Instead of just using `trySend`, I used `channel.trySend` and it worked just fine.

`channel` is inside channelFlow context.